# How to get the data from realtime firebase and use it to login

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[My Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1N9a.png)

I want to get that data and compare it in the text box for my login

Comment: Please could you provide the code you're using to provide more insight so we can help, and possibly the Database structure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
  onTap: () async {
                          
                          final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore
                              .instance
                              .collection(usernameController.text)
                              .get();
                          final List<DocumentSnapshot> documents = result.docs;
                          try {
                            DocumentSnapshot kjnk = documents[1];
                            print(kjnk.id);
                            print(kjnk[kjnk.id]);
                            if (kjnk[kjnk.id] == passwordController.text) {
                              util.showToast("Success");
                              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/second");
               
                            } else {
                              util.showToast(
                                  "Please Enter the correct Password");
                              Navigator.pop(context);
                            }
```

Comment: Your code reads from Firestore, while the screenshot in the question is from the Realtime Database. While both databases are part of Firebase, they are completely separate and the API from one doesn't work on the other.